# Regular Expression does not work properly in Adonis Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, adonis.js

> I have tried several regex found on SO and as google resulted.

I am trying to use `regex` as validating rule in `adonis js` as

```
first_name: 'required|regex:[a-zA-z]+([\s][a-zA-Z]+)*$'
```

My goal is to achieve this;
**regex which accepts only single space between words,**

```
John Doe - True //(single space between words and no space before and after)
 John Doe - True //(single space between and one space before)
John doe  - true //(single space between and one space after)
jhon  doe - false //(two spaces between words. )
John3 Doe  -  false
3John Doe  - False
```

> I have tried several regex which works on online regex checkers but
>   does not responds properly in adonis

here in one https://regex101.com/r/pN8xL5/312

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please see this answer : [forum.adonisjs.com/t/rule-not-accepting-regex/](https://forum.adonisjs.com/t/rule-not-accepting-regex/5322/14?u=crbast)

You need to use `rule()` for regex. Something like :

```js
const { validate, rule } = use("Validator");

const rules = {
      first_name: [
        rule(
          "required"
        ),
        rule(
          "regex",
          [a-zA-z]+([\s][a-zA-Z]+)*$
        ),
        ...
      ]
    };
```

Comment: this expression arise syntax error in my case

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Adonis, but it looks like it tried to match the **whole** string.

Using *regex101* web site, I came up with the following regex, with *g* and
*m* options:

```
^ *([a-zA-Z]+) ([a-zA-Z]+) *$
```

It matches:

- `^` - start of row,
- `*` - an initial sequence of spaces (if any),
- `([a-zA-Z]+)` - a non-empty sequence of letters (the first capturing group),
- - a space
- `([a-zA-Z]+)` - another non-empty sequence of letters (the second capturing group),
- `*` - a trailing sequence of spaces (if any).
- `$` - end of row.

In *regex101* it matches first 3 input rows from your sample, just as you want.

As I suppose, your regex should check only a **single** string,
so in the final version of regex:

- remove leading *^* and trailing *$*,
- remove regex options,

so your regex to be used in Adonis should be:

```
 *([a-zA-Z]+) ([a-zA-Z]+) *
```